# setVisibility of TableRow using CheckBox in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on android studio, but I cannot understand why my code does not work.

```
    if (paidCheck.isChecked()) {
        paidRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        paidRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

As you can see, variables end with Checks are CheckBoxes, and end with Rows are TableRows.
My problem is even if I tap the CheckBoxes, TableRows do not appear in the app. Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Could you please attach layout file for this and more code related to this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you have implemented gets called once whenever your activity or Fragment loads up, it does not gets called whenever you check or uncheck again.

What you need is a `CheckedChangeListener` which will be as follows

```java
paidCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked){
               // do somtheing when is checked
               paidRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 }else{
                       paidRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }

        }
    });
```